# How make a polygon button like this?

Tags: html, css, button

I created a button polygon chevron like the one in this link -> [Image (Button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtNHv.png). I've made the code like below, but for the blue component on the left I don't know how to make it, and also when I give it `border-radius`, `box-shadow` to look exactly like in the image is also not working properly. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```css
body{
  background-color:#cacaca;
}

.button{
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left:50px;
}

.button-shape{
  background-color:#fff;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#16215C;
  padding:13px 45px;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 75%, 95% 100%, 3% 100%, 10% 70%, 0 0);
  border-radius:0 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16);
}

.button-shape:hover{
  background-color:#16215C;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" class="button-shape">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use an SVG, much simpler

Comment: `box-shadow`and `border-radius` are "working," you just can't see it because you're clipping it out with the `clip-path`

Comment: how to use ```border-radius``` to make it visible even using ```clip-path```? because the edges are very sharp, I don't want to be like that @k88lawrence @Paulie_D

Comment: the borders `border-radius` is acting on are the true borders of the element, not the clipped portion we can see. you'd have to change your `clip-path` to change how the "edges" look.

Comment: change ```clip-path``` to what? @k88lawrence

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) filter to the button:

```css
filter: drop-shadow(-4px 0px 0px #0862A8);
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#cacaca;
}

.button{
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-left:50px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-4px 0px 0px #0862A8);
}

.button-shape{
  background-color:#fff;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#16215C;
  padding:13px 45px;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 0, 100% 75%, 95% 100%, 3% 100%, 10% 70%, 0 0);
  border-radius:0 0 10px 0;
}

.button-shape:hover{
  background-color:#16215C;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" class="button-shape">Read More</a>
</div>
```

---

Also FYI, if you want to achieve exactly the same result, you can also use images:

[image]

Comment: how to use ```border-radius``` to make it visible even using ```clip-path```? because the edges are very sharp, I don't want to be like that

Comment: @SirPalermo It's not likely to use `clip-path` to create an irregular shape with curvatures. You probably need to create a custom svg to achieve the exactly same result. Also, if the sizes of the buttons are almost the same, using the pure png image as a background is also easier.

Comment: so it's impossible to give ```border-radius``` to the clip path? I want to use SVG, but I can't give a slide right animation (using an inset) in an SVG, is it right? @Hao Wu

Comment: @SirPalermo You can combine `border-radius` with `clip-path`, but `border-radius` only works for the four corners of the bounding box, not the corners of svg. So that won't be very useful.

Comment: oh can you give an example from my code in post above?